# how to detect when setTextZoom() finishes its loading in a webview?

Tags: android, webview

I use setTextZoom() to make the text of html files bigger or smaller in a webview.

```
private void makeTextBigger() {
    WebSettings settings = webview.getSettings();
    settings.setTextZoom(settings.getTextZoom() + 10);
}
```

It works fine for smaller files, but when the file is large, it takes a few seconds to see the change. This few seconds delay to see the change makes the user thinking that zoomIn is not working well! So I would like to detect when `setTextZoom()` finishes its work so that I can show a progress bar at that time.

I tried `WebViewClient` as the following code, but it does nothing.

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){
        public void onPageStarted(WebView wv, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            show_WebviewLoadingProgressBar();
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView wv, String thisUrl){
            hide_WebviewLoadingProgressBar();
        }
    });
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At last I have figured out a way to do this:) (I am new to programming. So please correct me if I am wrong.)

I declare three member variables:

```
private long pageLoading_StartTime = 0;
private long pageLoadingTime = 0;
private static final long loadingTimeThreshold = 500; // in millisecond
```

Then for every webpage loading, I keep record of the loading time like this:

```
webview.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient(){

        public void onPageStarted(WebView wv, String url, Bitmap favicon){
            pageLoading_StartTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime(); //reset pageLoading time
            pageLoadingTime = 0;
        }

        public void onPageFinished(WebView wv, String thisUrl){
            pageLoadingTime = getPageLoadingTime();
        }
    });
```

getPageLoadingTime() method:

```
private long getPageLoadingTime(){
    long currentTime = new Date(System.currentTimeMillis()).getTime();
    return currentTime - pageLoading_StartTime;
}
```

Then in zoom buttons OnClickListeners:

```
zoomIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startOnClickAnimation(v);
            makeTextBigger();
            show_Progressbar_IfRequired();
        }
});
```

show_Progressbar_IfRequired():

```
private void show_Progressbar_IfRequired(){
    if(pageLoadingTime > loadingTimeThreshold){
        show_WebviewLoadingProgressBar();
        hideProgressBar_After_PageLoadingTime(pageLoadingTime);
    }
}
```

If progressbar is visible, I hide it after the pageLoadingTime. I used a handler to do this.

```
private void hideProgressBar_After_PageLoadingTime(long interval){
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            hide_WebviewLoadingProgressBar();
        }
    };
    handler.postAtTime(runnable, System.currentTimeMillis()+interval);
    handler.postDelayed(runnable, interval);
}
```

And now it works as I wanted. This website has helped me a lot in solving this issue. So many many thanks to all of you.